# Limit of Quotient exponential distributed Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of independent and exponential distributed random variables, where $X_n \sim \mathrm{Exp}(\lambda_n)$ with $\lambda_n = (1-\frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1}$. Let $s<r$ and define:

$$Y_n = \frac{X_1^s + X_2^s + \ldots + X_n^s}{X_1^r + X_2^r + \ldots + X_n^r}$$

Show that $Y_n$ converges almost surely to a limit $Y$ and determines its value.

---

Firstly, I split up $Y_n$ to $$\frac{X_1^s + X_2^s + \ldots + X_n^s}{n} \cdot \frac{n}{X_1^r + X_2^r + \ldots + X_n^r}$$ and determine the limit for each factor. I should only need the limit for $(X_1 + X_2 + \ldots + X_n)/n$ and apply the continuous mapping theorem for $f_1 = x^s$ and $f_2= x^r$. My problem is to find this limit, cause the law of big numbers doesn't help here cause the RVs are not identically distributed. I hope some can give me a hint on this one.

Comment: $(1-\frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1} \to e^{-1}$ as $n$ increases

Comment: Yeah I know, so the SLLN says that $\frac{S_n - \mathbb{E}(S_n)}{n}$ converges to 0 a.s. But my problem is to evaluate $\mathbb{E}(S_n)/n$ it should be $\mathrm{e}$ but the series isn't easy to evaluate

Comment: $X_i^s$ is weibull distributed for $s>0$..

Comment: Can you say $\frac{X_1^s + X_2^s + \ldots + X_n^s}{n} \to e^{-s}$ as $n$ increases? And then $Y_n \to e^{r-s}$?

Comment: As n increases $\frac{X_1 + X_2 + \ldots + X_n}{n} \to \frac{\mathbb{E}(S_n)}{n} = \mathrm{e}$ with continuous mapping theorem for $f=x^s$ the limit gets $\mathrm{e}^s$. But how to evaluate $\mathbb{E}(S_n)/n$? With $\lambda_n$ from above the series gets $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-\frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1}$